# In Qt 4.8 MS Excel ActiveX control in QWidget has no Ribbon for data formatting

Tags: qt, activex, ole, activeqt, activex-documents

I am trying to open a MS Excel workbook in my qt widget. With the following code I can successfully open the workbook in my qt application. I am using QAxWidget embedded in a QWidget.

```
     QAxWidget *excel=new QAxWidget;
     QWidget *mainWidget=new QWidget;
     QHBoxLayout *hbox=new QHBoxLayout;
     hbox->addWidget(excel);
     mainWidget->setLayout(hbox);
     excel->setProperty("Visible", true);
     mainWidget->show();
     excel->setControl("C:\\active\\excel.xlsx");
```

**Here is my output:-**
[image]

**My Question:**

As it is clear from the above output excel workbook is open to view and edit cells but I want to show office Ribbon and Tabs for formatting the workbook. How to show Ribbon/Formatting UI Controls so I can do formatting on the workbook?

Comment: Even after two day there is no comment and answers to this question. Is my question clear to understand? If any doubt please write in comments.

Comment: Isn't just a matter of layout? I'm not sure about this though